# Rails server run under production mode but access database under development-database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I found an strange issue.

I run `rails server -e production`, and put `binding.pry` in my controller.

And the Resque `rake resque:work QUEUE='*'` will trgger the  method later.

First,  it will create a new instance in  production database.

Then, I dig into `binding.pry`

I try to  pull all the data from the model by  `MODEL.all`

Unexpectedly, I found the data is all from development database.

So, I ran into console `rails c` and `RAILS_ENV=production rails c` to check what's the problem

I found the instance was created at production mode correctly, but how come in the following methods will pull the data from development mode??

There are Passenger and Nginx run on my server and I run another server by `rails server -e production` to debug.

Thanks

Comment: Are you asking why `rails c` pulls from development?

Comment: i think its depend on how you set your database.yml?

Comment: can you post your config/database.yml ?

Comment: i guess you have same db name and configuration for development as well as production in your database.yml